# Time durations are not obeying [h]:mm:ss format for all data values

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am currently using some `Time duration calculation` function to determine the total durations. Now the function giving the output as expected format `[h]:mm:ss` for the below dates: `11/15/2012  8:45:43 AM` and `12/7/2012  8:45:43 AM` - the duration is `87:45:55` (***corect***) but for this `1/3/2013  8:45:43 AM` and `9/6/2012  8:04:58 AM` - here the duration in the excel column has been stored as `4/28/1900  12:40:45 AM` (***INCORRECT***). Now my question is why it is not get stored in the excel column as others?

**CODE**

```
Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2)
If Not (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) Then
    TimeSpan = "00:00:00"
ElseIf CDate(dt2) > CDate(dt1) Then
    TimeSpan = TimeSpan(dt2, dt1)
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    'MsgBox(DateDiff(CDate(dt1) - CDate(dt2)))
    TimeSpan = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text((CDate(dt1) - CDate(dt2)), "[h]:mm:ss")

    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
        'MsgBox(CDate(dt1))
        'MsgBox(CDate(dt2))
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
End Function
```

Please help me to understand what the bug is and what could be its FIX?

Thanks

Comment: What is incorrect about the duration `4/28/1900 12:40:45 AM`?  It looks correct to me.

Comment: @VBSlover - as you don't say in what way your actual result(s) differ from the expected, I can only suspect that mapping *durations* to *dates* in a conspiracy with leap days/years are the cause of your problem. Are your results one day off?

Comment: @RBarryYoung If you see carefully that in my description i mentioned all the time duration should come `[h]:mm:ss` format.But the incorrect one not came like that! that is the issue.Please read my problem description!

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner expected result should come `[h]:mm:ss` format but it came `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm` for some inputs, and the inputs are also mentioned there!

Comment: You write "the duration is 1/22/1900 12:00:00 AM *but* for this..." - this implies that 1/22/1900 12:00:00 AM is the correct result ... now you say it is not. You should edit your question.

Comment: @VBSlover: Yes, as KekuSemau points out, you are contradicting yourself and that makes impossible to figure out what you are really trying to ask.  Please write your problem descriptions more clearly and self-consistently.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I am done, and please re read and it would make sense now!

Comment: @VBSlover - make sure to look at Sean's answer and to re-consider your format specs.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yes I will! thanks to bring into my notice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec     = "..\data\updsheet\save.xls"
Dim oExcel : Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWBook : Set oWBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(goFS.GetAbsolutePathName(sFSpec))

Dim dtA : dtA = #1/3/2013 8:45:43 AM#
Dim dtB : dtB = #9/6/2012 8:04:58 AM#
Dim dtC : dtC = #11/15/2012 8:45:43 AM#
Dim dtD : dtD = #12/7/2012 8:45:43 AM#

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
    dtA, dtB _
  , dtC, dtD _
)

Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(aTests) Step 2
    WScript.Echo "----", i, aTests(i + 0), "<>", aTests(i + 1), aTests(i + 0) - aTests(i + 1), aTests(i + 1) - aTests(i + 0)
   On Error Resume Next
    WScript.Echo "A", oExcel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(aTests(i + 0) - aTests(i + 1), "[h]:mm:ss")
    If Err.Number Then WScript.Echo "A", Err.Description
   On Error GoTo 0
   On Error Resume Next
    WScript.Echo "B", oExcel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(aTests(i + 1) - aTests(i + 0), "[h]:mm:ss")
    If Err.Number Then WScript.Echo "B", Err.Description
   On Error GoTo 0
    WScript.Echo
Next

oExcel.Quit
```

and its output (German locale!):

```
---- 0 03.01.2013 08:45:43 <> 06.09.2012 08:04:58 119,028298611112 -119,028298611112
A 2856:40:45
B Die Text-Eigenschaft des WorksheetFunction-Objektes kann nicht zugeordnet werden.

---- 2 15.11.2012 08:45:43 <> 07.12.2012 08:45:43 -22 22
A Die Text-Eigenschaft des WorksheetFunction-Objektes kann nicht zugeordnet werden.
B 528:00:00
```

proves:

1. @VBSlover's description of the problem can't be trusted. There are about 22 days/528 hours between #11/15/2012 8:45:43 AM# and #12/7/2012 8:45:43 AM#. It's everybody's guess where the 87:45:55 come from. (so the question should be downvoted)
2. Other than @KekuSemau stated, the WorksheetFunction.Text() returns resonable string values, as long as you feed it the correct parameters. (so if the attempt to answer isn't made on topic and useful, it should be downvoted)
3. @VBSlovers code contains an OERN. So if there is a problem in the assignment to TimeSpan (the function name), the return value of that function is undefined. No wonder some of the cells get filled with spurious data, that's what you get, when you hide errors.

**Update I: wrt @Sean's proposal:**

If you run

```
Option Explicit

Dim dtA  : dtA  = #1/3/2013 8:45:43 AM#
Dim dtB  : dtB  = #9/6/2012 8:04:58 AM#
Dim Sean : Sean = "2856:09:45"
Dim Ekke : Ekke = "2856:40:45"

WScript.Echo "!German Locale!"
WScript.Echo "dtB", dtB
WScript.Echo "dtA", dtA
WScript.Echo "Sean", Sean, "=>", addTS(dtB, Sean)
WScript.Echo "Ekke", Ekke, "=>", addTS(dtB, Ekke)

Function addTS(dtX, sHMS)
  Dim aParts : aParts = Split(sHMS, ":")
  addTS = dtX
  addTS = DateAdd("h", CLng(aParts(0)), addTS)
  addTS = DateAdd("n", CLng(aParts(1)), addTS)
  addTS = DateAdd("s", CLng(aParts(2)), addTS)
End Function
```

output:

```
!German Locale!
dtB 06.09.2012 08:04:58
dtA 03.01.2013 08:45:43
Sean 2856:09:45 => 03.01.2013 08:14:43
Ekke 2856:40:45 => 03.01.2013 08:45:43
```

you'll realize that there must be a bug in Sean's code.

Comment: @VBSlover  `On Error resume next` is always a source of confusion... if at all possible filter the input instead

Comment: @Ekkehard I agree that my 87:45:55 output isn't correct,it was wrongly pasted.But what would I like to say there that the output format was wright,which is not the case of anotherone .

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Judgemental comments relating to other replies should be made in the comment section below that reply, and not within your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A change to your `TimeSpan` calculation will allow you to get the hours. I used the `DateDiff` that you commented out (which wasn't in the correct format) and changed the function away from the `.Application.WorksheetFunction` to an inbuilt function:

```
TimeSpan = DateDiff("h", CDate(dt2), CDate(dt1)) & _
    Format((CDate(dt1) - CDate(dt2)), ":nn:ss")
```

When I go tho the immediate window, and type

```
?timespan("1/3/2013 8:45:43 AM","9/6/2012 8:04:58 AM")
```

it gives me an answer of

```
2856:40:45
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, yes - used `mm` instead of `nn`, so it was giving months! updated answer

Comment: +0.333 each for idea, implementation, and willingness to *improve* the code.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not care for your format here. You send text into an Excel cell, and Excel treats this as any input and tries to convert it to whatever it sees fit. You can however code the *numberformat* directly:

```
With [some Range Object]
    .NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
    .Value = TimeSpan(..., ...)
End With
```

...where the TimeSpan function should rather return a date value.

This cannot be done from within your TimeSpan-function. If you want that, you have to pass a reference to the target range as another parameter and let the function write to it directly (and add the format).

Comment: but VBSlover uses WorksheetFunction.Text() that converts the value param according to the format param into text/a string.

Comment: Although I agree that my answer was ill-tested and did _not_ lead the right spot, you still have misread my point. Writing a string into an Excel cell does not in all cases write _exactly_ that string to the cell, Excel may in some cases apply a differing format for a date/time value.